# Does the interrupt granted by "Refire the Forge" prevent an Avenger from falling unconscious?

Tags: dnd-4e, divine, avenger

[Refire the Forge](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=12206):

> Effect: Until the stance ends, you regain hit points equal to your Dexterity or Intelligence modifier each time you hit an enemy with an attack. Additionally, until the stance ends you can use the power Refire the Forge Attack, at will.
>
> Refire the Forge Attack
>
> Immediate Interrupt      Melee 1
>
> Trigger: You are bloodied or reduced to 0 hit points by an enemy’s attack
> Hit: 1[W] + Wisdom modifier damage and ongoing 5 damage (save ends).

(bits cut)

Does an `Immediate Interrupt`, which triggers on "being reduced to 0 HP" provide healing in time to prevent going unconscious from the brief moment of negative HP?

Comment: Is that in a book somewhere?

Comment: The compendium search page says Dragon issue 385 (though, oddly, the actual compendium entry does not indicate a source at all)

Comment: Looking at the answers here, I'm just waiting for someone to load up Visio and post a flowchart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Yes**, the **Refire the Forge** attack goes off prior to fully resolving the hit against you.
- Does it prevent you from going unconscious?  Read on!

Here is the sequence to follow

1. An attack hits an Avenger and the damage reduces him to 0.
2. The Avenger declares his intention to use an **Immediate Interrupt** - the Refire the Forge attack <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=12206)</sup>
3. The first attack (and damage) are set aside for now.  From the text of Immediate Interrupt: `An immediate interrupt lets you jump in when a certain trigger condition arises, acting before the trigger resolves.`
4. The Refire the Forge Attack is now rolled and resolved:

   - **It missed:** Now resolve the first attack, **the Avenger is at 0 hp and unconscious**.
   - **It Hit!:**  Add the temp HP from Refire the Forge.  Also, *did the Avenger's attack kill the attacker or otherwise invalidate the attack?*

     - **Yes:** w00t!  The initial attack is fully negated.  Also from the Interrupt definition, `If an interrupt invalidates a triggering action, that action is lost`  **The Avenger is definitely conscious**
     - **No:** Now you have to re-apply the damage from the initial hit, remembering your temporary hp.  *Is the Avenger still at 0 hp?*

       - **Yes**: Too bad, nice try though!  **The Avenger is unconscious**
       - **No**: Rock and Roll!  **The Avenger is conscious**

Comment: I think this would be a bit clearer, and unchanged in results if (1) read "and the damage will reduce", and the did the refire hit "No" read "Now you finally apply the damage from..."

Comment: The "Also, did the Avenger's attack kill the defender" clause also kicks in if the Avenger manages to apply some other status (such as unconscious) or effect (such as pushed out of range/reach) that invalidates the triggering attack.

Comment: @Simon - the trigger says "You are bloodied or reduced to 0 hp".  It happens, and then you smack them (and hopefully invalidate it). Your note about other status effects is quite valid and I will incorporate it, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**: the healing comes in time to prevent unconsciousness, but whether you fall unconscious **depends** on the actual damage dealt, your current hit points and your Dexterity or Intelligence modifier.

The Immediate Interrupt takes place before its trigger happens, so you are actually conscious when you use the attack.

- *Example 1:* You are currently at 15 hp and are going to receive a blow
  that would inflict you 17 damage. You then use the immediate interrupt and connect.
- *Example 2:* You are currently at 15 hp and are going to receive a blow
  that would inflict you 24 damage. You then use the immediate interrupt and connect.

The rider effect of regaining hit point takes place as you land the blow.

- *Example 1 and 2:* You hit, but you don't kill the target. You regain 3 hp (Dex or Int modifier) and go up to 18.

Then, the triggering (enemy's) attack hits, and it could actually leave you conscious if it doesn't hurt you much. If this is the case, the **Refire the Forge Attack** has took place anyway (many immediate interrupt powers are designed for nullifying their trigger).

- *Example 1:* You take the 17 damage
  from the triggering attack. You drop
  to 1 hp.
- *Example 2:* You take the 24 damage from the triggering attack. You drop
  to -6 hp and are unconscious.

Comment: As a note, since all healing starts at 0, if the II hits, it will *always* leave you conscious.

Comment: Uhm... when the II hits you have not already recieved the triggering punishment, so you are still over zero.

Comment: @Brian - Immediate Interrupts effectively happen *before* the trigger.  So, if you're at 5 HP before the attack hits, the II gives you 10 HP, but the triggering attack deals 16 damage, you still end at -1 HP.

Comment: It seems we are saying the same thing. Or am I missing a point?

Comment: Rather than "It depends" I would suggest, "Yes, but"  IMO, the important thing is that the Interrupt triggers and goes first.

Comment: I originally wrote "Yes". "It depends" has been edited by @Iszi. Now I have rollbacked.

Comment: @Erik, ah - cool.  +1 away!

Comment: I threw in "It Depends" because it's a situational thing.  The question is, "Does [X] prevent [Y]" and the answer varies with factors [A] and [B].  Preventing unconsciousness through this power is dependent upon the PC's DEX/INT modifier, and the damage done by the triggering attack.  So, the answer to this question will not *always* be "Yes".  If the question was *"Can* [X] prevent [Y]", then it would be.

Comment: Ok! I, instead, have read the question with a focus on the timing: _Does the II [..] provide healing **in time** to prevent going unconscious [..]?_ . The second part of the question seemed purely hypothetical to me. Of course you are right in pointing out that the consciousness is prevented only if the healing received is higher that the difference between the damage dealt and your current hp.

Comment: Edited for clarification. @Iszi was right.

Comment: side note: if _Refire..._ drops the attacker, you take no damage at all!

Comment: Correct. I've not added it as an "Example 3" to not stuffing the answer, but of course it is the most augurable condition ^_^